# I am trying to add custom icons in my wordpress menu a tag

Tags: wordpress

Well I am trying to add icons in `a tag` in WordPress menu items. I added it from admin dashboard by enabling css classes options. But it is added in `li` items instead of `a` tag.
Is there any way to add icons in `a` tag dynamically?. Please see attached images there are two images

1. Image is dynamic menu (trying to replicate design from image no. 2)
2. Image is static menu

My PHP code for wordpress menu

```html
<?php
   wp_nav_menu( array(
      'theme_location'   => 'menu-1',
       'menu_class'      => 'nav main-menu menu navbar-nav',
       'container_class' => 'nav-inner',
       'fallback_cb'     => false,
     ));
?>
```

[image]

Passing this value appears icons in a tag of all menu items. But as I guess this is not the appropriate way to implement icons dynamic in wordpress.

```
'link_after'       => '<i class="ti-angle-down"></i>',
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to use custom css classes, but there is other solutions.

Here is two different ways to do that :

https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-image-icons-with-navigation-menus-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for your effort but no luck